# Python Django - Variables shared between multiple users

Tags: python, django, celery

I am working on a project written in python and using django to build a website as well. I have a function which is pulling the information from a website and putting that information into a dictionary. When the users refresh the browser, the website will show the latest update of that dictionary, so far I am doing the updates being triggered by the browser but this is only for testing.

So, after several headaches I could finally install celery and make it work, so I have my website running with "python manage.py runserver", and at the same time I have two celery processes running: "celery -A tasks worker -l info pool=solo" and "celery -A tasks beat --loglevel=info". So far everything seems to be working until I realized that the dictionary is being updated but not for all users who access the website, looks like each user has his own instance of the dictionary.

So the idea is to have celery updating the dictionary with the information pulled from the website and all users just seeing what is inside the dictionary variable. Can I do this without a database or a file being written every time the update function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Coming back on this, it seems my problem was Celery. Looks like Celery was running its own instance of my program when I ran the commands mentioned above. Then when I started the webserver using "python manager.py runserver" that had nothing to do with celery tasks. I stopped using celery and now I am using a background scheduler for doing the same, everything works now.